# Suppress node-gyp log messages on MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, logging, couchbase, node-gyp

I am trying to install `couchbase` using `npm`. I have the latest version of `node` (v9.6.1) and `npm` (5.8.0) installed. It seems the prebuilt binary is not available for my environment. So it is trying to build the binaries locally.

During `npm install`, I see a lot of messages like below:

```
prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.3.0
prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds/couchbase-v2.4.3-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ /Users/XXXXXX/.npm/_prebuilds/https-github.com-couchbase-couchnode-releases-download-v2.4.3-couchbase-v2.4.3-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/releases/download/v2.4.3/couchbase-v2.4.3-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/releases/download/v2.4.3/couchbase-v2.4.3-node-v59-darwin-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=9.6.1 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=darwin)
  COPY ../deps/lcb/include/libcouchbase/libuv_io_opts.h
  COPY ../deps/lcb/include/libcouchbase/plugins/io/libuv/plugin-libuv.c
  COPY ../deps/lcb/include/libcouchbase/plugins/io/libuv/plugin-internal.h
  COPY ../deps/lcb/include/libcouchbase/plugins/io/libuv/libuv_compat.h
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/bucketconfig/bc_cccp.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/bucketconfig/bc_file.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/bucketconfig/bc_http.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/bucketconfig/bc_static.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/bucketconfig/confmon.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/http/http.o

  ../deps/lcb/src/http/http.cc:219:27: warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]
lcb_host_t reqhost = {0};
                      ^
                      {}
1 warning generated.
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/http/http_io.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/jsparse/parser.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/lcbht/lcbht.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/lcbio/connect.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/lcbio/ctx.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/lcbio/iotable.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/lcbio/ioutils.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/couchbase/deps/lcb/src/lcbio/manager.o
```

I assume these logs are from `node-gyp rebuild` execution.

Is there a way to suppress these logs? Is there a place we can set the `log-level` for `node-gyp`?

Comment: node does have a npm loglevel you can try setting it  like this npm instal `--loglevel info`, in your case as these are warnings you can set it to silent`--loglevel silent`, but this will unfortunately suppress most of the logs of your npm install of couchbase